# Where do DBA questions go in the trilogy?

Tags: discussion, questions, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

Backing up databases, tuning of database engines, etc. all make sense to me for Server Fault.

But where do questions [like this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/137483/multiple-columns-in-a-single-index-versus-multiple-indexes) go?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com is now active

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBAs wear a lot of hats.  It depends on what hat you're wearing at the time.

Are you optimizing a single sql query or indexing on a single database?  Then it's probably stackoverflow.  Are you worrying about your maintenance plans, backups, server configs, etc?  Then it's probably serverfault.

Comment: And if you are looking for a remote client to edit Database data, you are looking for SuperUser

Comment: Regarding *"Are you optimizing a single sql query or indexing on a single database"*, Wouldn't that be better on dba.SE?

Answer (score 9):

There was [an Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260/databases?referrer=qdAOyW41ttVXXXrT0S5BhA2) to pull these questions together. It is now launched at **[Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)**.  There are many database questions that may even seem like they belong on SO, SF or SU, but in fact belong on another site.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say SO, definitely.

There will be many more database design/programming experts there than on SF, and what's being asked is essentially a database programming question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with code(read: SQL queries directly) then it belongs on SO. Everything else belongs on SF.

Answer (score 0):

That is SO because it's a table/index design/tuning question.