# Can I post SQL Server related questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do DBA questions go in the trilogy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48429/where-do-dba-questions-go-in-the-trilogy)

Can I post SQL Server related questions in this site?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot post "can I post ***" questions here - post them at http://meta.stackoverflow.com Edit the post and its title to reflect your question.

Comment: SQL Related questions are welcome (look at the questions page - lots of SQL questions there). However, questions about what is allowed or not are not so welcome.

Comment: Only *distinct* questions.

Answer (score 4):

You should post SQL Server related questions at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Post questions about Stack Overflow (including this one) to [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you sure can! SQL programming questions that is. Setting up server and that kind of stuff should go to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

(why not try and just ask the question or search, you will soon see other sql server questions and maybe even one that answers yours)